# Smooth Scrolling in Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheets

<strike>Google Sheets currently scrolls by entire rows and columns, which can be a jarring experience (especially if there are large rows or columns).</strike>

Anyone know how to make the scrolling smooth?

Fixed as of 3/4/2024!

Thanks to @Mintvbz for pointing out [the announcement from Google](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2024/03/smooth-scrolling-in-google-sheets.html)

Comment: As someone who really wants this solution to get solved, which stack exchange site is better for this question? I saw other Google Spreadsheet questions on here, as well as the google-spreadsheets tag, so I thought it would fit here

Comment: The best workaround I've found is to save the Google sheet as a zip/website and open it in your browser. That's only feasible if the content is read-only for your purposes.

Comment: Here is what you can do. File > Share > Share to Web

Comment: Looks like Google finally fixed it https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2024/03/smooth-scrolling-in-google-sheets.html

Answer (score 8):

File -> Version history -> See version history

This opens the side pane and goes into a different mode, so it's not optimal, but it does enable smooth scrolling.

Would be nice if someone could reverse engineer this mode and write an extension that emulates it without having to open version history pane.. or if Google could just fix it themselves.

Comment: FYI, I took a look, and the only reason it works in that mode is because it puts the table in an iframe with scrollbars. The default view has custom scrollbars. Probably possible to override with some javascript hacks, but would be much easier for the Sheets team to fix.